# Вывести из текстового файла “input.txt” в файл “output.txt” только четные по счету строки

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, ввод

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>



using namespace std;

int main()
{   
int fl = 1;
FILE* f1;

fopen_s(&f1, "input.txt", "r");

char* str = new char[255];
FILE* f2;
fopen_s(&f2, "output.txt", "w");

if (!f2) {
    cout << "error 2" << endl;
    return 0;
}

if (!f1) {
    cout << "error 1" << endl;
    return 0;
}

while (!feof(f1)) {
    fgets(str,255,f1);
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        if (str[i] == '\0') {
            fl++;
            if (fl % 2==0) {
                fputs(str, f2);
            }
        }
}
fclose(f1);

return 0;}
```

не знаю как поделить строки на четные и нечетные

Comment: А что это вы такое делаете тут: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        if (str[i] == '\0') {`??  И еще - вот так `while (!feof(f1))` - неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Раз у вас С++, то и используйте средства С++.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    in >> noskipws;
    for(char c, even = 0; in >> c; )
    {
        if (even) out << c;
        if (c == '\n') even = 1 - even;
    }
}
```

Проверки, что файлы открыты, допишите сами.